# How is it ensured that char* can be used to access the exact underlying bytes of an object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to [basic.lval](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8), it is legal to access an object through `char`; however, according to [basic.compound](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4), `char*` is not pointer-interconvertible with something like `int*`, meaning that they may result in different values during casting.

Thus the code below:

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4);
int a = 0xFFEE2211;
char* b = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
assert(b[0] == '\x11'); // check whether it's little-endian.
```

may result in a `b` with a different address value from `&a` whose type is `int*`. So my question is how is it ensured that the first byte read by `b` is `0x11` rather than like `0x22`? More generally, which rule ensures that the memory bytes of an object can be fully accessed by `char*` as if a byte array with a size of `sizeof(obj)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It currently isn't ensured. Technically, forming a pointer to anything but the first byte through the `char*` pointer has undefined behavior, because any pointer arithmetic on `b`, including `b[0]` has undefined behavior. There is also no proper definition at the moment how the value of `*b` should be determined as it is not specified to be the value of the object representation, but rather the value of the `int` object itself. So that's probably undefined behavior as well.

The proposal [P1839](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592) is trying to fix that, although I am not sure at the moment whether the proposed wording would require a cast to `unsigned char*` instead of `char*`.

But even with that, it is implementation-defined which bits would be read from the `int`. That would be determined by endianess and an implementation is also permitted to use mixed endianess. For example the first byte in the object representation could be `0x22` and the second byte could be `0x11`.

Comment: This proposal seems to only guarantee that memory read of an object with continuous layout is legal rather than access(which includes writes), so how about `b[0] = 1`? So first, if it's illegal, the so-called `accessed by char` in basic.lval seems to just be `read by char`; and second, how can we determine whether an object has a continuous layout apart from that it's standard-layout?

Comment: @o_oTurtle The aliasing rule only makes certain accesses undefined behavior. It does not imply that the remaining cases have defined behavior. Write access is not in scope of the paper and more difficult to specify. Objects have guaranteed contiguous memory layout if they are standard-layout _or_ trivially-copyable. If your type is neither, then there is no guarantee that accessing object representation as a sequence of contiguous bytes would make sense. But an implementation can (and will be) more permissive than what the standard defines. The standard only specifies the minimum required.

Comment: @user17732522: The best way to specify semantics would be to recognize that any storage which is "owned" by a program and doesn't contain non-PODS objects simultaneously holds, throughout its lifetime, all PODS of all types that will fit, but then recognize that seemingly-independent accesses via incompatible lvalues are *generally* unsequenced.  Such an abstraction model wouldn't match the way compilers like clang and gcc presently behave, but *the Standard's object-lifetime model doesn't either*.  Allowing compilers to treat accesses as *generally* unsequenced, but then recognizing...

Comment: ...that certain constructs would force sequencing, would allow most useful aliasing-related optimizations while making it clear what programmers would need to do in order to access storage in "unusual" ways.  Under present rules, given `T1 *p,x; T2 *q,y; int flag;`, a compiler given `*p = x; *q=y; if (flag) *p = x;` would need to ensure that if `p` and `q` identify the same storage, it's left holding the last object written.  Under a sequencing-based model, however, the lack of any intervening actions that convert or derive a `T1*` or `T2*` to or from anything else would mean that...

Comment: ...the stores would be unsequenced, allow the write to `*q` to be reordered across one of the writes to `*p`, and thus allow the writes to `*p` to be consolidated, eliminating the need for the conditional test.